# Fresh install of Xenserver 6.2 , cannot load tools in Guest Win7

Tags: xenserver, xen

I've just started testing the XenServer 6.2 offering.. it's awesome so far.. I've event loaded all the patches and hot fixes, and started a windows 7 guest image.

I want to install tools, but whenever I click the `install tools` boxes.. I'm taken to my VM console and nothing loads.

It's a brand new guest, and most of the advice is for those with previous versions of tools loaded.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one responded I checked back into the Xen Server instance.  I felt pretty stupid when I saw this, but you need to select the `tools_iso` manually when NOT in fullscreen mode..

it does NOT automatically eject your media like it claims.. no biggie.

[image]